# Как удалённо менять местами CardView элементы

Tags: java, android

В приложении для Android на Java, планирую сделать список из CardView. Где будут товары с описанием и фото. Мне нужно чтобы после публикации приложения я могу их менять местами удалённо. Возможно через FireBase или другими методами. Как это лучше всего сделать? Подскажите. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вероятнее всего для отображения списка вы будете использовать RecyclerView (Хотя с ListView тоже самое). Он принимает список для отображения. В каком порядке вы этот список сформируете у себя в приложении, а таком порядке ваши элементы и отобразятся. Так что вы можете у себя на БЭК-е формировать нужный вам порядок, а в приложении просто прокидывать его не меняя порядка.